# Automating Hadoop with Neo4j

Tags: hadoop, neo4j

What could be the best way to use Neo4j and Hadoop?
I have to show the output in an admin panel.
My constraints are - large amount of data and query operations.

What I am currently thinking is,

Bring data into hadoop, perform ETL operations and write it back to the system. Convert this into a job and set it for repititive execution. Use Neo4j on this exported data. Is this the right way?

When searched about it, I found an article

> In the past there were some approaches that used Hadoop to quickly generate Neo4j datastores directly. While this approach is performant, it is also tightly coupled to the store-format of a certain Neo4j version as it has to duplicate the functionality of writing to split-up store-files. With the parallel neo4j-import tool and APIs introduced in Neo4j 2.2, such a solution is no longer needed. The import facilities scale across a large number of CPUs to maximize import performance.

Does this mean in terms of large datasets Neo4j no longer needs Hadoop for data processing?

Comment: That would depend if your data is conformed to the format expected by `neo4j-import`. You may not need HDFS or YARN, but Spark can still perform ETL and processing power onto Neo4j

Comment: @cricket_007 True spark could do it as well, but is repeated execution of the scripts possible? I mean, run a job that executes an ETL operation every 5 hours which feeds it into Neo4j?